# I am getting an error when trying to use this rotation matrix on a matrix of vectors

Tags: matlab, rotation, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

Im not even sure if I need to rotate every point in the vector. I have been trying to resolve this for a couple of days and im not sure what the error message is saying about the new vectors.

The issue is that this object I am displaying on a screen is positioned incorrectly and very obviously needs to be aligned properly.[This is the object and the approximate position on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aunwo.png)

[This is where the item should actually be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVjuM.png)

```
theta = -45; % to rotate 45 counterclockwise
rot_mat = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];

for i = 1:nr
    tdims(i,1:4) = cos(anglesRad) .* radius(i) + ptb.xcenter; % cos = x,
    tdims(i,5:8) = -sin(anglesRad) .* radius(i) +ptb.ycenter; % sin = y 
    for j = 1:length(radius)
        for k = 1:tdims(:,1:8)
                x = tdims(j,k);
                y = tdims(j,k+4);
                v = [x;y];
            transvector= rot_mat .* v
            tdims(j,k)= transvector(1)
            tdims(j,k+4)= transvector(2)
        end
    end
end
```

ptb.xcenter is the center of the screen (x (column) and ptb.ycenter is the center of the screen (y (row)

Comment: What does `for k = 1:tdims(:,1:8)` do? Hint: type `1:tdims(:,1:8)` into the Command Window and see if the result matches your expectation. Another hint: the two values on either side of the `:` operator must be scalars, but `tdims(:,1:8)` is an array!

Comment: I have since posting this changed the code, i realized the problem you are pointing out; I don't know how to conceptualize what I need using MATLAB functions. Therefore I have decided to go another way. Thank you!